# session management in android

Tags: android, session-management

I successfully developed one login form with mysql database via soap webservices.Here I wish to make session management but I am not able to develop. Please help me.

If u need coding part refer to this [link](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-login-activity-with-mysql.html)(me used same code for my login form):

Here I have made following modifications.

- added logout button on login page.
- if i clicked login button means it is successful means goto next activity otherwise stay in login page.the next activity have to passing logged person username.now i like to clicked logout button means it is move to login page.ok stillnow successfully developed.but now in my emulator i clicked back symbol means it is go to that displayed username.so here i ll make session concepts..how can i ll make session concepts here...because i can't able to develop dis part...please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use SharedPreferences like this:
1. Store username in SharedPreferences after successfully logging in.
2. Delete username from SharedPreferences after successful logout.
3. Override the next activity onResume() method and check for username from SharedPreferences.
if (pref.getString("username") == null) {
session expired; redirect to login activity.
}

**OR**

Clear activity stack when doing logout operation.

    Intent intent  = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

[link to shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)